# MQL4 CArrayObj how can i set reserve to 0 or avoid it completely?

Tags: mql4

MQL4 CArrayObj member function At(n) returns zero and member function Total() displays 5 instead of 3 and At(n) returns 0 at index 0-1 and the expect value at 2-4. So my expected data is at 2-4 and the reserve i suspect is at 0-1. How can i stop CArrayObj from reserving space?

I tried setting the CArrayObj member function Reserve to 0, but it is set to ignore 0 as seen in the below

```
bool CArrayObj::Reserve(const int size){
   int new_size;
//--- check
   if(size<=0)
      return(false);
//--- resize array 
if(Available()<size)
     {
      new_size=m_data_max+m_step_resize*(1+(size-Available())/m_step_resize);
      if(new_size<0)
         //--- overflow occurred when calculating new_size
         return(false);
      if((m_data_max=ArrayResize(m_data,new_size))==-1)
         m_data_max=ArraySize(m_data);
      //--- explicitly zeroize all the loose items in the array
      for(int i=m_data_total;i<m_data_max;i++)
         m_data[i]=NULL;
     }
//--- result
   return(Available()>=size);
}
```

I am expecting the CArrayObj to be 3 only, as i want it to be.

Comment: It seems to be bad idea to edit the basic classes without any need. Are you sure that you have nothing at index=0 and 1? maybe you placed `NULL` there? if you can show your MCVE code (e.g. you adds only 3 objects and receive `.Total()=5` or something else, that would be the easiest way to help you

Comment: Okay, well I didn't edit it since is a bad idea, but rather I just created a simple array with a basic functionality as the one I wanted. Thanks for the help.